# optionparser pass an array to ruby file

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I have a trouble with passing an arguments to my ruby file. IE,

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = 'Usage: mp3split.rb [options]'

  opts.on('-f', '--filename fName1,fName2,fName3', Array, 'absolute or relative pathes to file') { |f| options[:filenames] = f }
end.parse!
```

This approach requires me to write this commands:

```
ruby mp3split.rb --filename fursov_13.mp3,fursov_14.mp3,fursov_14_2.mp3,fursov_15.mp3,fursov_16.mp3,fursov_17.mp3
```

But I want to get array by this:

```
ruby mp3split.rb --filename fursov_13.mp3 fursov_14.mp3 fursov_14_2.mp3 fursov_15.mp3 fursov_16.mp3 fursov_17.mp3
```

How can I implement this functionality? I can't find anything helpful about this in docs.

Answer (score 3):

With `OptionParser` you can’t. There is a workaround, though, when there is the only list you need to handle that way and you won’t pass other arguments to the script. `OptionParser` splits the input by spaces *before* it processes it. The unkeyed arguments remain in `ARGV` global constant after parsing. Assuming everything described above is met, here we go:

```
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  options[:filenames] = []
  opts.banner = 'Usage: mp3split.rb [options]'        
  opts.on('-f', '--filename fName1 fName2 fName3', Array, 
          'absolute or relative pathes to file') do |f|
    options[:filenames] |= [*f]
  end
end.parse!

options[:filenames] |= ARGV
```

I apparently fixed another glitch within your code: `options[:filenames]` should be *appended* not *overwritten* on every occurence of `-f` switch, `OptionParser` supports `script -f f1 -f f2 -f f3`.

Comment: Maybe you mean `options[:filenames] ||= ARGV` instead of `options[:filenames] |= ARGV` ? I can't find `|=` method in the ruby api

Comment: `a |= b` is a ruby-wide shorthand for `a = a | b`. On arrays it is a [union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-7C).

Comment: Thanks, but I want exactly what I want. Is there any other ruby libraries?

Comment: How do you expect this parser to handle `-f a.txt -g` where -g is perfectly valid existing file name?

Comment: I needn't `-g` flag in my parser :)

Comment: You were asking whether there is an option parser, that makes what you want. Since `-f a.txt -f` is ambiguous for any parser that permits arbitrary amount of options separated by the same symbol as option markers themselves (space in your case,) your claim is ambiguous. You might parse `ARGV` as I suggested, or force commas as file list delimiter, or even write your own Turing-incomplete parser for such a specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I was shocked to learn that OptionParter can't do such a simple thing, so I switched to Thor, for example:

```rb
require 'thor'

class EmqxCLI < Thor
  desc 'add_user USER_ID PASSWORD [IS_SUPERUSER]', 'Add a user (optional: set true/false for is_superuser)'
  def add_user(user_id, password, is_superuser = false)
    emqx = EmqxApi.new
    emqx.add_user(user_id, password, is_superuser)
  end

  desc 'remove_user USER_ID', 'Remove a user'
  def remove_user(user_id)
    emqx = EmqxApi.new
    emqx.remove_user(user_id)
  end

  desc 'list_users', 'List users'
  def list_users
    emqx = EmqxApi.new
    emqx.list_users
  end
end

EmqxCLI.start(ARGV)
```

Which I can now run with:

```
$ ruby emqx.rb add_user user1 pass1
```

It also generates a lovely output when running without arguments:

```
# ruby emqx.rb
Commands:
  emqx.rb add_user USER_ID PASSWORD [IS_SUPERUSER]  # Add a user (optional: set true/false for is_superuser)
  emqx.rb help [COMMAND]                            # Describe available commands or one specific command
  emqx.rb list_users                                # List users
  emqx.rb remove_user USER_ID                       # Remove a user
```